# Determine probability that one set is closer to a random point than another set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have two sets that never intersect on a interval.

How do we rigorously determine the probability that one set is closer to a random point than another set. (Closest being the set intersects with the random point). How do we make this rigorous? Can we create a new measure?

By intuition I expect, for example

1) The irrationals would have a probability of 1 compared to the rationals. A random point will always be "on" the irrationals, while the rationals are infinitesimally close.

2) A set countable and Dense in R would have a probability of 1 compared to a set countable and non-dense in R.

3) A set countable and dense in R cannot have a probability compared to another set countable and dense in R. Both sets can be as close to the random point as possible.

Comment: In the abstract I think there's a rigorous definition along the lines you propose - but I dont think it works for the examples that you want it to work for.  In particular, the distance between any point in (0,1) and the set of irrationals, by the usual definition of distance from a point to a set, is 0 - and so is the distance between any point in (0,1) and the set of rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to work inside $[0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ to "normalize" things. This isn't essential, but makes more sense in a context where we want the maximum "size" to be $1$ (given that we're talking in terms of *probability*).

---

Per Steven Stadnicki's answer, distance is close to but not quite what we want here. However, as far as I can tell the only twist you want to add is that we should distinguish between "arbitrarily close to" and "exactly" - e.g. an irrational should be closer to $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ than to $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

At this point we can introduce a simple notion of preference. For $A,B$ disjoint sets, say that $x$ **prefers $A$ to $B$** iff we have $$\exists a\in A\forall b\in B[d(x,a)<d(x,b)].$$

Some quick observations:

- $\sqrt{2}$ prefers $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ to $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ as desired - take $a=\sqrt{2}$. More generally, if $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$ then $x$ prefers $A$ to $B$.
- If $A,B$ are each dense and $x\not\in A\cup B$ then $x$ doesn't prefer $A$ to $B$ or $B$ to $A$.

Now given two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, we get two new sets $A_{\triangleright B}$ and $B_{\triangleright A}$ given by $$A_{\triangleright B}=\{x: x\mbox{ prefers $A$ to $B$}\}\quad\mbox{and}\quad B_{\triangleright A}=\{x: x\mbox{ prefers $B$ to $A$}\}.$$ We'll always have $A\subseteq A_{\triangleright B}$, $B\subseteq B_{\triangleright A}$, and $A_{\triangleright B}\cap B_{\triangleright A}=\emptyset$. Of course there may be points in neither set.

> Incidentally, it's easy to actually compute $A_{\triangleright B}$: it's just $$A\cup(cl(A)\setminus cl(B))\cup \{x: d(x,A)<d(x,B)\},$$ where $d(y,U)=\inf\{d(y,u): u\in U\}$. That is: everything in $A$ already, plus everything "infinitesimally close" to $A$ which isn't "infinitesimally close" to (or in) $B$, plus everything strictly closer to $A$ than to $B$ in the usual sense.

It seems, then, that the probability you're interested in is just **the ratio of the measures of these sets**: $$Prob(A\triangleright B)={m(A_{\triangleright B})\over m(B_{\triangleright A})}$$ *if that ratio is defined*.

This agrees with each of the examples you've given: e.g. if $A,B$ are disjoint, dense, and countable, then we have $A_{\triangleright B}=A$ and $B_{\triangleright A}=B$, each of which have measure zero, yielding an undefined probability. **But note that all of this still boils down to a measure calculation** - namely, we need to assign numbers to $A_{\triangleright B}$ and $B_{\triangleright A}$ somehow in order to get a ratio to care about.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly define such a quantity, but it won't do what you want.  For instance, the notion of distance between a point and a set can be defined as $d(p, A) = \inf_{q\in A} d(p,q)$; you can then say that the 'relative closeness index' of $A$ over $B$ (on, say, the unit interval) is the measure of the set $S\subseteq[0,1] = \{s: d(s,A)\lt d(s,B)\}$.  I'd bet (but don't hold me to this) that this set is even guaranteed to be measurable and that therefore the value you're after is well-defined.

But the problem is that it won't solve the problems you're after, because $d(p,A)$ can't distinguish between $A$ and $\mathrm{cl}(A)$ at all; since you're taking an infimum, adding in limit points doesn't affect the result at all. In particular, $d(p,\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]) = d(p, (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\cap[0,1]) = 0$ for all $p\in[0,1]$, since there are both rationals and irrationals arbitrarily close to any point.

Comment: A random point would be "on" the irrationals while the rationals are arbitrarily close. Could we create an alternate definition?